# Google Apps Script にローカルファイルをアップする方法

Tags: google-apps-script

Google SpreadSheet などで編集できる Google Apps Script の xxxx.gs というファイルなどを、GoogeleのWebサイト上で更新するのではなく、ローカルに配置してあるテキストファイルをアップする方法はありますか？

ご存知でしたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

正しい手順かは自信がありませんが、新規スクリプトの編集画面でローカルのファイルを
ブラウザの画面上にドラッグアンドドロップすれば、ファイルの内容が挿入されます。